# Product list page Toolbar issue

Tags: magento-2.2.1, toolbar, category-view

I have issue regarding category page.

While I click on mode switcher in grid view to list view its not 
 working. and also try to change Sort by value and Show number of product its not working.

Following configuration setting 
`Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront`

[image]

Current Magento version is 2.2.1,
Any idea what is wrong with this ?

Comment: Have you checked the log files. ?

Comment: @zedBlackbeard there is not single error related to catalog module, and alos no error showing in console

Comment: You can change Products per page on grid Allowed values with 9,18,27 etc.